# How to wait for multiple events?

Tags: windows, delphi, winapi, delphi-7

There are few threads in a Application in which I am working with.
Those threads are setup to FreeOnTerminate and I am not allowed to change this behavior.
I saw something weird in the way the old developer was awaiting for some signals in the main thread, As Followed:

Let:

```
var FWaits: array of TEvent;
var FThreads: array of TBkgThread;
const C = 10;
```

for Each Thread, we have an Event, then `Length(Threads) = Length(FWaits)`

```
  for I:= 0 to C-1 do
  begin
    FWaits[I]:= TSimpleEvent.Create;
    FThreads[I]:= TBkgThread.Create(FWaits[I]); //The handle of the Event
  end;

  [CODE]
  for I:= 0 to Length(FWaits)-1 do
    case FWaits[I].WaitFor(INFINITE) of
      wrError: begin 
                 NotifyError; //Code Irrevelant; 
                 Break;
               end;
      wrSignaled: TryNotifyUser(I); //Code Irrevelant; 
      wrAbandoned: TryNotifyAbandon(I); //Code Irrevelant; 
      wrTimeout: TryNotifyTimeOut(I); //Code Irrevelant; 
    end;
```

This is programmed in the worker thread:

```
destructor TBkgThread.Destroy;
begin
  inherited;
  FEvent.SetEvent;
end;
```

I don't know if signaling the event after calling inherited is ok in this case, but this is not the problematic part.

I know of WaitForMultipleObjects, so I tried to reduce the code marked with `[CODE]` to this:

```
var Handles: array of THandle;

  SetLength(Handles, Length(FWaits));
  for I:= 0 to Length(FWaits)-1 do
    Handles[I]:= FWaits[I].Handle;

  case WaitForMultipleObjects(Length(Handles), @Handles[0], TRUE, INFINITE) of
    WAIT_FAILED: begin Label1.Caption:= 'WAIT_FAILED'; RaiseLastWin32Error; end;
    WAIT_OBJECT_0: Label1.Caption:= 'WAIT_OBJECT_0';
    WAIT_ABANDONED_0: Label1.Caption:= 'WAIT_ABANDONED_0';
    WAIT_TIMEOUT: Label1.Caption:= 'WAIT_TIMEOUT';
  end;
```

But it is raising an windows error: code 6.

How can I correctly wait for multiple events?

[UPDATE]

```
TBkgThread = class(TThread)
  private
    FEvent: TEvent;
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
  public
    constructor Create(AEvent: TEvent);
    destructor Destroy; override;
  end;

  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    edThreads: TLabeledEdit;
    Button1: TButton;
    Button2: TButton;
    Label1: TLabel;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    FThreads: array of TBkgThread;
    FWaits: array of TEvent;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

{ TBkgThread }

constructor TBkgThread.Create(AEvent: TEvent);
begin
  inherited Create(False);
  FreeOnTerminate:= True;
  FEvent:= AEvent;
end;

destructor TBkgThread.Destroy;
begin
  inherited;
  FEvent.SetEvent;
end;

procedure TBkgThread.Execute;
var I,J,K: Integer;
begin
  while not Terminated do
  begin
    for I:= 0 to 10000 div 20 do
      for J:= 0 to 10000 div 20 do
        for K:= 0 to 10000 div 20 do;
    Sleep(1000);
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  I, C: Integer;
begin
  C:= StrToIntDef(edThreads.Text, 0);
  if C > 0 then
  begin
    SetLength(FThreads, C);
    SetLength(FWaits, C);
    for I:= 0 to C-1 do
    begin
      FWaits[I]:= TSimpleEvent.Create();
      FThreads[I]:= TBkgThread.Create(FWaits[I]);
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var I: Integer;
    Handles: array of THandle;
begin
  for I:= 0 to Length(FWaits)-1 do
    FThreads[I].Terminate;

  SetLength(Handles, Length(FWaits));
  for I:= 0 to Length(FWaits)-1 do
    Handles[I]:= FWaits[I].Handle;

  case WaitForMultipleObjects(Length(Handles), @Handles[0], TRUE, INFINITE) of
    WAIT_FAILED: begin RaiseLastWin32Error; Label1.Caption:= 'WAIT_FAILED'; end;
    WAIT_OBJECT_0: Label1.Caption:= 'WAIT_OBJECT_0';
    WAIT_ABANDONED_0: Label1.Caption:= 'WAIT_ABANDONED_0';
    WAIT_TIMEOUT: Label1.Caption:= 'WAIT_TIMEOUT';
  end;

//  for I:= 0 to Length(FWaits)-1 do
//    case FWaits[I].WaitFor(INFINITE) of
//      wrError: begin Label1.Caption:= 'WAIT_FAILED'; Break; end;
//      wrSignaled: Label1.Caption:= 'WAIT_OBJECT_0';
//      wrAbandoned: Label1.Caption:= 'WAIT_ABANDONED_0';
//      wrTimeout: Label1.Caption:= 'WAIT_TIMEOUT';
//    end;
end;
```

Comment: I don't know if an SSCCE is necessary. I could post if needed.

Comment: You cannot wait for free on terminate threads. You cannot retain any reference to them after they start. You need to reconsider the constraint that the design cannot be changed. That makes solving the problem rather tricky.

Comment: I am waiting for Events, not for threads

Comment: I can't change that code right now... Just the Main Thread part

Comment: So why are you retaining thread references. There's nothing you can do with them. You need to delete the `FThreads` array.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan There is nothing wrong to FThreads array they are being freed naturaly. This code is needed as part of a process that    forks a job and then continue in the main thread. Those Events are passed as references to the Thread, As you can see in the first piece

Comment: Step 1 is to fix your error handling. You have to call `GetLastError` immediately. You don't. You call `SetCaption` on a label. That's going to screw things up. So fix that and find out what `GetLastError` really tells you.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Ok, thanks, I'll change to see

Comment: No, there's really no need to keep `FThreads`. What are you going to do with them? You cannot ever refer to them. The fact that you keep those references, and tell me that you cannot remove them, tells me that there is more going on that you have not told us. I don't know why you won't make an SSCCE.

Comment: @All you post the SSCCE, wait please

Comment: As an aside, the call to `FEvent.SetEvent` is poor in the destructor. If the constructor raises then `FEvent` could be `nil`. I'd put that in an overridden `Terminate` method.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, Terminate is not virtual. Do you mean DoTerminate?

Comment: @UweRaabe Indeed I do. Thanks.

Comment: You must not call FThreads[x].Terminate on a `FreeOnTerminate` thread.

Comment: @LURD How should I terminate them?

Comment: If you need to stop the threads prematurely, you must have a synchronizing object to do that, like TSimpleEvent.

Comment: ... or set FreeOnTerminate to false. The problem happens when the thread is already finished and freed when you call Terminate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You pass the address of the second wait handle instead of the first. Replace

```
@Handles[1]
```

with

```
@Handles[0]
```

Some other suggestions:

1. You have to call `RaiseLastWin32Error` (or indeed `RaiseLastOSError`) immediately so that `GetLastError` can retrieve the error code for the desired API call. You call it after setting a label caption, something that will very likely result in an incidental call to `SetLastError`.
2. It is better to set the event in an overridden `DoTerminate` method. That way you don't call methods on `FEvent` from the destructor. If the constructor raises, then `FEvent` can be `nil`.
3. You should not retain references to free-on-terminate threads. Since the thread object can be disposed at any time, you can readily end up holding a reference to a destroyed object.

That final point is very important. You clearly don't adhere to that point when you loop around all the threads calling `Terminate` on them. You need to decide whether to use free-on-terminate, or whether you want to retain references to the threads. You have to pick one or other option. You cannot have it both ways.

If you wish to use free-on-terminate threads, then you would need to use a separate event to signal cancellation. Pass that event to the thread on construction. Instead of testing for `Terminated` in the thread method, test for that event being set. Set the event when you wish to cancel.

However, all of this is very strange. You say that you wish to use free-on-terminate threads, but then you also want to wait for all the threads to complete. The use of free-on-terminate threads then forces you to create extra events to deal with the waiting and the cancellation. Because you cannot retain references to the thread. Now, you've got to free the events that you created. So, you've avoided having to free the threads, but replaced that with a requirement to free the events.

Your approach is much more complex than it needs to be. In my view you should:

- Stop using free-on-terminate threads.
- Remove all the events.
- Wait on the thread handles.
- Free the threads when the wait completes.

Only use free-on-terminate threads when you don't need to wait for the thread.

Comment: I believe that was a typo in the SSCCE, but I'll check anyway

Comment: Nope, That was the problem... I don't believe

Comment: I had not even seen that comment from `TOndrej` when I wrote the answer. But yes, props to Ondrej.

Comment: About the final point, The code is using that way ONLY to terminated the threads. You are saying that I should only use FreeOnTerminated when the THREAD terminates itself?

Comment: I added more text to the end of the answer. Basically I believe that you need to stop using free-on-terminate. Because you are waiting for the threads.